# TS lint plugin for VS code doesn't track closed files

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

I'm using `VSCode 1.17.2`, and using [tslint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) plugin with it to track lint errors. As of now it is working fine with opened files and showing errors on files with red marker and giving error in problems tab. But it is not tracking closed files. Am I missing any configuration? Currently I am using default configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) for the extension:

> The extension lints an individual file only. If you want to lint your
>   entire workspace or project and want to see the warnings in the
>   Problems panel, then you can:
>
> use gulp that or define a script inside the package.json that runs
>   tslint across your project.
>
> define a VS Code task with a [problem matcher](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_processing-task-output-with-problem-matchers)
>   that extracts VS Code warnings from the tslint output.
>
> For example, here is an excerpt from a package.json file that defines
>   a script to run tslint:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "tslint-script-demo",
>   "version": "1.0.0",
>   "scripts": {
>     "lint": "tslint tests/*.ts -t verbose"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "typescript": "^2.2.2",
>     "tslint": "^5.0.0"   }
> }
> ```
>
> Next, define a Task which runs the npm script with a problem matcher
>   that extracts the tslint errors into warnings.
>
> ```
> {
>     "version": "2.0.0",
>     "tasks": [
>         {
>             "type": "npm",
>             "script": "lint",
>             "problemMatcher": {
>                 "base": "$tslint5",
>                 "fileLocation": "relative"
>             }
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```
>
> Finally, when you then run the tslint task you will see the warnings produced by the npm script in the Problems panel and you can
>   navigate to the errors from there.
>
> Here is the complete [setup example setup](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/tree/master/tslint-tests).